# Is there any way to tell if the result of a complete round robin is ODD or EVEN?

Tags: probability

Doing a classical cut and shuffle, is there any way to predict or assign a probability to the result being odd or even?

Take all the cards in the deck. Cut them somewhere. Then do a perfect shuffle. For various deck sizes and cut points, the number of perfect shuffles required to return the deck to the original order varies.

**The cards are shuffled until the original order is returned.**

En-route, there are factors (the periods of each card as they return to their original positions.)

If the result is ODD, then the periods are also all ODD.

So far, I can see that they are more EVEN than ODD.

However, if the result is EVEN, the factors can be both ODD and EVEN (but not all ODD).

Given that, is there any way to assign a probability to the likelihood of an ODD or EVEN outcome?

For example:

- Deck has 493 cards.
- Cut it at the 408th card into two parts A and B
- Let A be 0..K (inclusive)
- Let B be K+1 to the end.
- Shuffle the cards such that the B goes first, then an A, then a B. When the smaller list is done, then append the remainder as-is.

That's a standard card shuffle with a cut.

For this one, the result is even and requires 177,454,736,391,766,680 shuffles to return to the exact same order.

What I want to know is if anyone has experience with combinatorial math that can find a way to predict the ODD or EVEN status of the answer for any values of deck size and cut.

Comment: What do you mean by "a classic cut and shuffle"? And the term "round robin" usually relates to tournaments. For this question, is there some kind of tournament?

Comment: ok - I added that in the question.

Comment: Can you give an example to explain what you mean by the phrases "factors", "periods of each card", "the result is ODD"? To illustrate, perhaps use a small deck, say $5$ cards.

Comment: A perfect shuffle is just a uniformly random permutation, right? If so, isn't "cut" irrelevant?

Comment: Every card returns to its original position one or more times. We can call that the period. The number of shuffles required to bring it to the original order is always divisible by all the periods. So we have the deck size, the cut point, the factors (periods) .

Comment: So it's a fixed permutation, repeatedly applied? In other words, once the permutation is chosen, it's not changed?

Comment: Sure, call it that. Or we can even apply a compound permutation (applying a permutation twice, can be recorded and applied 10 times to make the result of 20 shuffles).

Comment: Since there's no tournament, isn't "round robin" the wrong term? Perhaps a more accurate title would be "Is there any way to tell if the period is odd or even?"

Comment: It can refer to a sequence or scheduling algorithm.

Comment: So by "the _result_ is odd", you mean the deck returns to its original order in an odd number of "cut-shuffles"?

Comment: A toy example with a deck of some fixed size $n$, where $n$ is very small, would help clarify the meanings of the terms.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/77547/discussion-between-saint-hill-and-quasi).

Comment: Ok, I misunderstood "perfect shuffle".

Comment: Does the cut point stay fixed? In other words, starting with the original deck, and a chosen cut point, does the same same cut point get used before each perfect shuffle, until the deck returns to the original order?

Comment: For the duration of the round of shuffles, yes. But you can cut it anywhere you want to start a new process. So the way of finding the ODD or EVEN must work with any deck size and and any cut.

Comment: I think I now understand the question. Thanks for the clarifications. I'll play with it.

Comment: For a deck of size $n$, and a random cut point $k$ with $1\le k \le n-1$ (i.e., $A$ has $k$ cards, $B$ has $n-k$ cards), let $p(n)$ be the probability that the period is odd. Testing empirically, as shown in the image https://imgur.com/gx5pKey, p(n) appears to slowly decrease on average, possibly approaching a positive limit.

Comment: OK - That is a fascinating chart. In other news I noticed too that the result is even is at least one even factor is present.

Comment: Yes, the full period must be a multiple of the period of each factor, so if any factor has an even period, the full period must be even.